# PHP - Alter URL to hide querystring and display page title instead

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a selection of pages which currently have a url which looks something like this:

`www.mydomain.com/directory/?id=123`

This displays a story from a mySQL table with the id of 123.

What I would like to know is whether it is possible to alter the appearance of the URL to look something like this:

`www.mydomain.com/directory/story-title`

I have the following page code...

```
<?php 

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/con.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = $id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($mysqli->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

echo $row['title'];

?>
```

And the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)/?$ /directory/index.php?id=$1
```

The original URL works fine, but not the new one.

Comment: Is the 'story-title' unique? In other words, can it be used as the ID?

Comment: Good point... Perhaps it should be `/123-story-title` instead... This would ensure it is unique by adding the primary key to the front.

Comment: No no, that wouldn't look good. Am writing an answer for you, give me a few mins

Comment: For this you need to do with .htaccess file. Here is a good example of [how to use .htaccess file for url rewriting](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide a variable in the URL if it is going to change from page to page... If the 'story-title' is unique for each page (it is a primary key in the database), then you can simple do an `.htaccess` rewrite and use the 'story-title' as the id.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ directory/page.php?story=$1
```

However, if the 'story-title' is not unique then you will have to implement a different sort of rewrite that uses the id but also displays the story title. Exactly how SO does it.

The following will rewrite this:

```
www.domain.com/directory/ID/STORY_TITLE/
```

to

```
www.domain.com/directory/page.php?id=ID
```

.htacess (not tested):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)/(.*)/?$ directory/page.php?id=$1&story=$2
```

Comment: OK, so I've done exactly this but I get a 404 page when I try the new URL. Is there anything else I need to change or could it be my hosts not allowing this kind of thing?

Comment: @Tom See my edit. I have added the option for a / at the end of the URL. There may also be other errors. Best thing to do is debug it :-) This should serve as a good starting point...

Comment: Any hints on the best way to go about seeing why I'm getting the standard server "Page not found" page?? I have no idea where I've gone wrong? Is there anything else I need to put into my htaccess file?

Comment: @Tom You need to go through the code and ensure everything is correct, such as a the page name, the name of the directory etc

Comment: See the edit in my post... I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: OK... I think I see the problem... the host uses a Zeus server rather than Apache

Comment: @Tom Yeah that would definitely cause a problem. Look into see how Zeus rewrites URL's

Comment: @Tom See here: http://www.names.co.uk/support/hosting/528-zeus_rewrite_rules_user_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

store story title in database and pass it (`story=story-title`) in URL instead of `id=123`

then write following .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ directory/index.php?story=$1
```

now you can access `www.mydomain.com/directory/?id=123` from `www.mydomain.com/directory/story-title`

Answer (score 0):

I do not precicely know about it, but here is something what I read someday.

A special string is used as a title and ID at the same time. It is also called "slug".
Slugs must be unique in your database.

Structure:

```
Title       | Text     | Slug            | ID
------------+----------+-----------------+--------
"Big title" |"HTML etc"| "story-title"   | 5
```

So you just use that slug to find a needed article.